# how to recreate button in excel VTO adds-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

i have this pieace of code which gets activated when i press a button on the ribbion

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
Excel.Range selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Excel.Range;

 if (selection != null)
{
 Button button = new Button();
 button.Text = "THIS IS A BUTTON";
 vstoDocument.Controls.AddControl(button, selection, name);
 button.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
// save the button state and name in custom properties 
 Excel.Worksheet sheet = Application.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
 sheet.CustomProperties.Add("btnName" "btn_1");
 sheet.CustomProperties.Add("text","THIS IS A BUTTON");
 sheet.CustomProperties.Add("selection", selection);
}

//the click event
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 MessageBox.Show("I got Clicked");
}
```

so this works when i press the button on the ribbion
the problem is when i save the excel and open it again the range does not get assigned in my startup code

```
 Excel.Application wb;
            wb = this.Application;

            if (wb.ActiveCell.Count > 0)
            {

                object docIndex = 1;
                Worksheet vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
                foreach (Excel.CustomProperty prop in props)
                {
                    if (prop != null)
                    {
                        string pn = prop.Name;
                        if (pn.Contains("selection"))
                        {
                           
                            Excel.Range selection = prop.Value as Excel.Range;
                            if (selection != null)
                            {
                                Button button = new Button();
                               vstoDocument.Controls.AddControl(button, selection, "btn_1");//get an error here
                                button.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
                                button.Text = "THIS IS A BUTTON";
                                button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

i get an error there saying

> System.OutOfMemoryException   HResult=0x8007000E   Message=Not enough
> memory resources are available to complete this operation. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY))   Source=   StackTrace:

Comment: Do you have any other aadd-ins or VBA macro that could erase the custom properties?